# Getting event types in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to have the type of an event from the event queue to decide certain actions (i.e. if it is a joystick event or a keyboard one), but the `dir` of events is an empty list:

```
for e in pygame.event.get():
    print dir(e)
```

Although in the documentation i read:

> The queue is a regular queue of pygame.event.EventTypepygame object for representing SDL events event objects

i can't access a `__dict__` attribute. The above code prints a bunch of empty lists: `[] [] [] []` etc. In pygame 1.9.4 installed from pip i could run:

```
if e.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
    e.__dict__["joy"]
```

and i could get the number of joystick button pressed, but this is not working in 1.9.4 installed with `sudo apt install` (on Debian):

```
print event.__dict__
AttributeError: event member not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do if-elif-elif with e.type.
First import the event constants you need to check from pygame.constants
For example

```
from pygame.constants import QUIT, MOUSEBUTTONDOWN
while true:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            #close the game
        elif e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            #mouse click
```

The dir() function gives the directory where a module is located, that doesn't work as you think